# Using jQuery mobile to reveal a hidden div is causing links to be loaded incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I am creating a search bar that is revealed when a trigger is clicked on.

I've used [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504745/1602221) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYVQy/2/) to reveal the hidden search bar div.

This is the js I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $searchBox = $('#search-wrapper #search-box');
    var $searchTrigger = $('.search-trigger');

    $searchTrigger.on("tap", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $searchBox.slideToggle();
    });
    $(document).on('tap', function (event) {
        if (!($searchBox.is(event.target)) && ($searchBox.has(event.target).length === 0)) {
            $searchBox.slideToggle();
        };
    });
});
```

The jQuery mobile is causing a bug. When I click on a valid link, a "loading" statement flashes on the screen and the page clicked has loaded in a messy way underneath the current page.

Comment: just a tip, "$('#search-wrapper #search-box');" could be "$('#search-box') as IDs are unique, so they're the same. No reason to specify 'the elem with ID thats under another elem with ID',

Comment: I decided to try it without jQuery mobile. The loading bug was no longer a problem and I'm still able to achieve the same effect I was looking for. Standard jQuery will have to do for now!

Comment: I changed the 'tap' to 'click' to deal with normal jQuery.