# When clicking or touching outside of a specific container

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch, containers

I am trying to close a specific element when clicking or touching outside of the container.

I know this doesn't work, but you get the idea:

```
$(document).on('touch', 'click', function (e) {
    var container = $('.sidebar');

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('body').removeClass('sidebar-opened');
    }
});
```

How do I do this correct? I am using the touch event of the jQuery mobile UI library.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like the solution on this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/20504745/486058 ?

Comment: Wow yes, exactly like that! Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle div on click or touch and hide on click/touch outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112404/toggle-div-on-click-or-touch-and-hide-on-click-touch-outside)